# Segue not happening immediately with AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, segue, avplayer, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I am making a tvOS app. I am creating a simple SHOW segue. In the destination view controller i want to play a remote video with `AVPlayerViewController`, but when when i press the button to make the segue, its not happening immediately. In fact, it waits for almost 2 to 3 seconds and then goes to the destination View Controller, where the video starts almost immediately. I think the segue is not happening immediately because AVPlayer is loading the video. I don't want this behaviour, what i want to have is to make the transition immediately and then may be show a activity indicator (spinning view) at destination View Controller.

Here is my code for the destination View Controller.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVKit


class PlayViewController : UIViewController {


    var avplayerVC : AVPlayerViewController?
    var videoUrlStr : String?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("In PlayViewController View Did Load")

        avplayerVC = AVPlayerViewController()

        let avAsset = AVAsset(URL: NSURL.init(string: videoUrlStr!)!)
        let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
        avplayerVC?.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem)

        avplayerVC?.player?.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
        avplayerVC?.player?.play()
        avplayerVC?.view.frame = (self.view?.frame)!
        self.view.addSubview((avplayerVC?.view!)!)

    }



    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        avplayerVC?.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }


    // MARK : AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate


}
```

Can anybody help me in achieving this behaviour? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `asset.loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys(keys: [String], completionHandler:)` This method will give you the ability to do some of the loading and then setup your player in the completion handler. You can pass any keys to this method, but some you might consider are duration, tracks, and playable.

The only other caveat I can think of is that after you have loaded these values you will need to dispatch your player interactions to the main thread.